# Distance of a 3d Point to a Poly Line Segment Algorithm

Tags: graphics, vector, 3d

I have a path, made up of n 3d coordinates, all connected in series, which can be seen in [this diagram](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/7915/segments.png).

I want to find the shortest distance between my point and the poly line segment. I can calculate the distance of a point from a single line segment, but I want to do it for a more complicated path.

Is there an algorithm for this that does not rely on testing every line segment to point distance and stores the minimum? Any pointers in the right direction would be great!

This is for a games project where I want to calculate the distance of the player from a river that exists in the game. The river will be represented with poly line segments.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a Sweep Line algorithm is appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Calculates the euclidean distance from a point to a line segmented path.
 *
 * @param v     the point from with the distance is measured
 * @param path  the array of points wich, when sequentialy joined by line segments, form a path
 * @return      distance from v to closest of the path forming line segments
 *
 * @author      Afonso Santos
 */
public static
double
distanceToPath( final R3 v, final R3[] path )
{
    double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE ;

    for (int pathPointIdx = 1  ;  pathPointIdx < path.length  ;  ++pathPointIdx)
    {
        final double d = distanceToSegment( v, path[pathPointIdx-1], path[pathPointIdx] ) ;

        if (d < minDistance)
            minDistance = d ;
    }

    return minDistance;
}


/**
 * Calculates the euclidean distance from a point to a line segment.
 *
 * @param v     the point
 * @param a     start of line segment
 * @param b     end of line segment
 * @return      distance from v to line segment [a,b]
 *
 * @author      Afonso Santos
 */
public static
double
distanceToSegment( final R3 v, final R3 a, final R3 b )
{
    final R3 ab = b.sub( a ) ;
    final R3 av = v.sub( a ) ;

    if (av.dot(ab) <= 0.0)              // Point is lagging behind start of the segment, so perpendicular distance is not viable.
        return av.modulus( ) ;          // Use distance to start of segment instead.

    final R3 bv = v.sub( b ) ;

    if (bv.dot(ab) >= 0.0)              // Point is advanced past the end of the segment, so perpendicular distance is not viable.
        return bv.modulus( ) ;          // Use distance to end of the segment instead.

    // Point is within the line segment's start/finish boundaries, so perpendicular distance is viable.
    return (ab.cross( av )).modulus() / ab.modulus() ;      // Perpendicular distance of point to segment.
}
```

The rest of the (self contained, no external dependencies) R3 3D vector algebra java package is here:
https://gist.github.com/reciprocum/4e3599a9563ec83ba2a63f5a6cdd39eb

part of the open source library
https://sourceforge.net/projects/geokarambola/